# k-modes Clusters Validation

Tags: self-study, clustering, categorical-data, validation

I am working on my thesis using R.

I have a dataset of mixed numeric and categorical variables. Since the variables are related to different "dimensions" of the same phenomenon, I believe it would make more sense to cluster the numeric variables using k-means algorithm and cluster the categorical variables using k-modes algorithm.

Now, I find validation of k-means results pretty straightforward: evaluate heterogeneity within clusters, analyze for each cluster how the variables move away from the mean of the overall population, etc. This process helps both defining the more appropriate number of clusters and describe the meaning of each cluster.

However, it is not clear how to apply this process to results of k-modes based on categorical variables. Do you have any suggestion or idea?

ps: binary variables are more related to the group of categorical variables, however, is it more appropriate to use the in k-means or k-modes?

Comment: My suggestion would be to abandon your proposed approach of using two different clustering algorithms and trying to integrate the results. Mixtures of data are common in applied analysis and modeling. Finite mixture models are an integrated approach to handling them. In the case of *clustering* mixture data, latent class clustering models such as *Latent Gold* software offer a reasonably easy solution. I'm not advocating *LG* for any reason other than the fact that, in my experience, it's the best tool for this purpose. The *LG* website has many, many academic papers on the topic.

Comment: @DJohnson thank you for your idea, latent class clustering is a new topic for me. However, I forgot to say that I am a student and I must work using open source stuff. In the beginning, my arbitrary decision was to try learning R and now I am developing all the project in R. Can you please extend why you think integrating the results of two different clustering algorithm is not recommended?

Comment: For this project, the objective is to obtain something like 20 or 25 clusters. I struggled a lot with this and in the end it came into my mind that the ideal situation would be have 4-6 clusters of k-means and 4-6 clusters of k-modes, then, integrating them with a pivot I could obtain the number of clusters required. On the other hand, running a k-means (one-hot encoding categorical variables) or k-prototypes with k = 20 did not generate meaningful results.

Comment: The point is that the integrated FMM framework accounts for dependencies that can be lost using two different algorithms. *LG* is not free but at about $1k for a license, it's not expensive either. I think they have a free trial period and a reduced price for students. Again, check out the papers referenced on their site (https://www.statisticalinnovations.com). Another excellent book is Frühwirth-Schnatter's *Finite Mixture and Markov Switching Models*.  As a student, do you have access to your university's proprietary statistical software, e.g., SAS? SAS has a FMM module that might work.

Comment: This is very important point you are showing me, thank you. For several reasons, I surely do not use LG. However, I will definitely check out the papers. Furthermore, since I have access to SAS Base and Guide I will further investigate this approach. I went through your answers and I found several extremely useful suggestions!

Comment: SAS also has a lousy third party latent class module but it may be better than nothing!

Comment: what about the one of R?

Comment: PolCA is an R module for latent class clustering but it requires discrete inputs, as such, it can be related to Clifford Clogg's MLLSA model. Otherwise, I'm not aware of any FMM clustering modules in R but it would be interesting if more knowledgeable CV participants were to suggest them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72379/discussion-between-seymour-and-djohnson).